# Excel VBA: Cannot delete multi columns by using if statement and for loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

1. Background & purpose.
   I want to delete multi columns in my "sheet1" based on specific column header.

For example: if column name = "First Name", "Surname", "DoB", "Gender", "Year"
Then delete entire of column.

And I use vba to do that.

- Button "Execute" in "Execution" sheet
- Data is saved in "Sheet1".
- Click on "Execute" button, macro will be executed and edit data in "sheet1".

**Here is my code**

```
Sub SPO_EditDocument_BUttonClick()

'Declare constant variable
Dim CellValue As String

'Edit SPO Documents.
'Consider worksheet"SPO"

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    '1. Loop and delete unnecessary columns
    LastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    For i = 1 To LastCol
        On Error Resume Next

        CellValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i)   'Get Column header

        If CellValue = "Firstname" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete

        ElseIf CellValue = "Surname" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete

        ElseIf CellValue = "DoB" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete

        ElseIf CellValue = "Gender" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete

        ElseIf CellValue = "Year" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End With  'End to process Worksheets

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

[Sample data table in sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE957.png)

1. **Problem**: When I execute my macro by clicking on button "Execute", just only 1 column is deleted at that time. Next click → next column is deleted (just can delete 1 column by one click).
2. **Question**: Why I can not delete all columns by 1 click with my code?
   What is the problem in this case?

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you so much for your attentions.

[Insert new columns before found cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zONH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another fast way

```
Option Explicit

Sub SPO_EditDocument_BUttonClick()
    Dim colNames As Variant, colName As Variant, actualColNames As Variant, foundColName As Variant
    Dim colsToDelete As String

    colNames = Array("Firstname", "Surname", "DoB", "Gender", "Year") ' build a list of column headers to be deleted

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' reference data sheet
        actualColNames = Application.Index(.Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Value, 1, 0) ' collect referenced sheet actual column headers

        For Each colName In colNames ' loop through your column headers to be deleted list
            foundColName = Application.Match(colName, actualColNames, 0) ' try finding current header to be deleted in actual headers list
            If Not IsError(foundColName) Then colsToDelete = colsToDelete & Columns(foundColName).Address(False, False) & " " 'if found update columns to be deleted index list
        Next

        If colsToDelete <> "" Then .Range(Replace(Trim(colsToDelete), " ", ",")).EntireColumn.Delete ' if columns to be deleted index list not empty, then delete thsoe columns
    End With
```

Comment: Hi @Shai Rado, That's great idea to delete column faster than what I did. Thank you so much for your advice. Really appreciated.

Comment: it worked perfectly and so easy to do maintenance. However, i have 1 more question. Could you please help me to solve this? I want to insert some new columns before some found cells and add formula to some of them. How should I do in this case? Please refer to my new attached image "Insert new columns before found cells" from my topic for more detail.

Comment: @Holmes, this deserves a brand new question from you.

Comment: Thank you. Here is my new post for this. Please help me to check it up. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951709/excel-vba-how-to-insert-multi-columns-and-cell-value-for-those-columns-into-ex

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the columns in reverse order.  To do that, change your line:

```
 For i = 1 To LastCol
```

to:

```
 For i = LastCol to 1 Step -1
```

Answer (score 0):

A faster way to delete multiple columns will be to use a `Range` object, in my code it's `DelRng`, which merges all `Columns` that pass your criteria to be deleted - using the `Union` function. So at the end, you just use the `Delete` function which takes a long time to process just once.

You can replace your multiple `ElseIf`s with a `Select Case`.

All objects which are nested in your `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` don't need to have `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` again, just use the `.` as a prefix to all `Cells` and `Range` objects.

You can have the much shorter, and faster code version like the code below:

***Modified Code***

```
Sub SPO_EditDocument_BUttonClick()

'Declare constant variable
Dim CellValue As String
Dim DelRng As Range

'Edit SPO Documents.
'Consider worksheet"SPO"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    '1. Loop and delete unnecessary columns
    LastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    For i = 1 To LastCol
        CellValue = .Cells(1, i)   'Get Column header

        Select Case CellValue
            Case "Firstname", "Surname", "DoB", "Gender", "Year"
                If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, .Columns(i))
                Else
                    Set DelRng = .Columns(i)
                End If

            Case Else
                ' Do nothing

        End Select
    Next i

End With  'End to process Worksheets

' if there's at least 1 column in DelRng >> delete the entire range (all columns) in 1-shot
If Not DelRng Is nothign Then DelRng.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Shai Rado. Nice sample to use Select Case to delete column for me.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, all of your answers work well and that's so useful to learn from your advice. ^^