# (Excel VBA) How to insert multi columns and cell.value for those columns into excel sheet before found cell?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

**1. Background & purpose**
I have a Excel sheet with table of multi-columns. 
I want to insert some columns(in yellow) via macro:

- "Total Cost" before "PIC" with formula: `Total Cost = Man-hour * C` 
  (where C is constant)
- "Reviewed.Date", "Reviewer", "Year" before "Month" and formula to determine fiscal year ("Year") based on "Inspected.Date".
  Ex: `Cell of Year = YEAR("Inspected.Date")+IF(MONTH("Inspected.Date")>=$D$1,1,0)`

Please refer to this picture for more detail.

[image: Insert New Columns to Excel]

**2. Problem & questions**
I can loop through all columns and check if Column.header = "PIC" or "Month", then insert new columns. But I don't know how to insert "Column header" and "value of all cells in that column" with formula because after inserting new column, position of some columns will be changed.
So, how can I do this with macro?
Any helps would be highly appreciated.
Thank you so much for your attention.

**3. Here is my current VBA**

```
Sub InsertNewColumn()
   'Edit SPO Documents.
   'Consider worksheet"Sheet1"

   With Worksheets("Sheet1")

       '1. Find out last columns & last row in target sheet.
        LastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row        
       '2.Loop through all columns and check column header. 
       '  If column header is "PIC" or "Month", then insert new column

        For i = LastCol To 1 Step -1            
            On Error Resume Next            
            CellValue = .Cells(1, i)   'Get Column header   

            'Insert column "Total Cost"
            If CellValue = "PIC" Then
                .Cells(1,i).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
                .Cells(1,i).Value2 = "Total Cost" 'Add column header            
            End If

            'Insert column "Year"
            If CellValue = "Month" Then
                .Cells(1,i).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
                .Cells(1,i).Value2 = "Year" 'Add column header

                'Add formula to year
                With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(i)
                    For j = LastRow To 2 Step -1                       
                        'Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, i).Formula = "=YEAR("Inspected.Date")+IF(MONTH("Inspected.Date")>=$D$1,1,0)"
                        'I want to add formula to determine fiscal year for cell of Year based on "Inspected.Date"
                        'but I dont know how to do
                    Next j               
                End With
            End If  
        Next i   
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True   
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add the code that you have to your question and highlight where it's broken or where you have problems.  Recording a macro while you do the tasks manually may give you some clues.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald: Thanks for your prompt response. I added my current vba to topic already. Please check it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a For ... Next loop so much as a reliable method of locating and inserting columns if they do not already exist.

```
dim c1 as variant, c2 as variant
with worksheets("sheet1")
    c1 = application.match("pic", .rows(1), 0)
    c2 = application.match("total cost", .rows(1), 0)
    if iserror(c2) and not iserror(c1) then
        .cells(1, c1).entirecolumn.insert
        .cells(1, c1) = "total cost"
    end if

    c1 = application.match("month", .rows(1), 0)
    c2 = application.match("reviewed.date", .rows(1), 0)
    if iserror(c2) and not iserror(c1) then
        c2 = application.match("inspected.date", .rows(1), 0)
        .cells(1, c1).resize(1, 3).entirecolumn.insert
        .cells(1, c1).resize(1, 3) = array("reviewed.date", "reviewer", "year")
        .range(.cells(2, c1+2), .cells(.rows.count, c2).end(xlup).offset(0, 4)).formula = _
            "=year(" & .cells(2, c2).address(0, 0) & ")+(month(" & .cells(2, c2).address(0, 0) & ")>=$d$1)"
    end if
end with
```

Note that I've modified your formula to the simpler form.

```
= YEAR("Inspected.Date")+(MONTH("Inspected.Date")>=$D$1)
```

Comment: Hi @Jeeped, thanks for your prompt answer. Your solution works like a charm. But I cannot understand clearly about your code. Could you please give me some explanation?

Comment: In an unused cell on your worksheet try `=match("inspected.date", 1:1, 0)`. It returns the column index number for the column with "Inspected.Date" in the top row. If "Inspected.Date" is not in the top row, you get #N/A (an error).

Comment: Got it. Once again, thank you so much for your explanation.

Comment: Hi @Jeeped, could you please help me this? If I want to add formula to "Total cost" from 2nd row ~ last row, how should I do?

Comment: wadr, you should ask a new question showing the effort you've put in toward a solution and explain the difficulties you are having completing the additional work.

Comment: Sorry for that stupid question. I solved it by using:    "LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row" and put down .Range(.Cells(2, c1), .Cells(LastRow, c1)).Formula = "my formula". Thanks for your attentions.